# Tool for managing secrets for VPN, passwords, etc

Tags: saas, vpn

I am running a company which needs to connect to multiple VPNs (different clients) and do some work on their infrastructure.

What tool would You recomend to securly store all this secrets? VPNs are managed by our clients and we often get one "company-wide" account from them...

Requirements:

- Saas
- share some vpn account details (secrets) between employees
- restrict access to selected employees